# How to send these type of Push Notifications in Android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

How to send these type of push notifications with Text and Image as shown in the below image?

[image]

Comment: start here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Customize the notification UI to show the notifications and To rotate images / control which image is displayed, you'd likely have to store images in the app and display it manually based on the content of the push.

Comment: Please let us know, if any answer is working for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we are careting `NotificationCompat.Builder` object Flow that Step

```
int icon = R.drawable.reload_logo;
```

Set Icon in `setSmallIcon()` methed

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        mContext);
                Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker("Reload.in").setWhen(0)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle("Reload.in")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(intent.getExtras().getString("message")))
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))

                        .setContentText(intent.getExtras().getString("message"))
                        .setStyle(notiStyle).build();
```

Comment: this is not push notification, but just notification

Comment: @xklakoux so tell me what is this

Comment: You need customize your notification UI, check here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Required notification contents

Comment: A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()

Comment: difference is that push notification comes from external server even when there is no app or background service running. The question regarded sending push notification, what you've shown is how to show a local notification.

Comment: just you think id app is not here in device tha first GCMListner Search package name if Package name exist in device than Show Notificaton outher vise discard message

Comment: i think do u not know pakage name will pay main roll in push natification

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        GCMResponse gcmResponse = new GCMResponse(data);
        sendNotification(gcmResponse);
    }

    private void sendNotification(GCMResponse gcmResponse) {
        FetchBitmap fetchBitmap = new FetchBitmap(gcmResponse);
        fetchBitmap.execute();
    }

    class FetchBitmap extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

        private GCMResponse gcmResponse;

        public FetchBitmap(GCMResponse gcmResponse) {
            this.gcmResponse = gcmResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Bitmap theBitmap = null;
            if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
                Looper.prepare();
            }
            try {
                theBitmap = Glide.
                        with(MyGcmListenerService.this).
                        load(gcmResponse.getImageUrl()).
                        asBitmap().
                        into(-1, -1).
                        get();
            } catch (final ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            return theBitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MyGcmListenerService.this, Home.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyGcmListenerService.this, requestID, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyGcmListenerService.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setContentTitle(gcmResponse.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(gcmResponse.getMessage())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            if (bitmap != null) {
                // Create the style object with BigPictureStyle subclass.
                NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notificationStyle = new
                        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
                notificationStyle.setBigContentTitle(gcmResponse.getTitle());
                notificationStyle.setSummaryText(gcmResponse.getMessage());

                notificationStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);

                notificationBuilder.setStyle(notificationStyle);
            } else {
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(gcmResponse.getMessage()));
            }

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

where `GCMResponse.java` is

```
public class GCMResponse {

    public static final String GCM_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String GCM_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String GCM_IMAGE_URL = "image_url";

    private String message;
    private String title;
    private String imageUrl;

    public GCMResponse(Bundle bundle) {
        message = bundle.getString(GCM_MESSAGE);
        title = bundle.getString(GCM_TITLE);
        imageUrl = bundle.getString(GCM_IMAGE_URL);       
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return Strings.nullSafeString(message);
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Strings.nullSafeString(title);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return Strings.nullSafeString(imageUrl);
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Do add `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'` to build.gradle
It helps download the image using url.

You just need to send 3 data points in GCM push and this listener will get the data, download the Image from URL and displays the push notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you get isPicture is not null in Push Notification json, then you should do like this:

```
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

if (isPicture.equals("true")) {
    URL url = null;
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(bigPicture);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPicStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    bigPicStyle.bigPicture(bmp);
    bigPicStyle.setBigContentTitle(contentTitle);
    bigPicStyle.setSummaryText(message);
    notificationBuilder.setStyle(bigPicStyle);
}

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Here `bigPicture` is your url of picture, which you want to show.